# Initializer not called for entities returned by saveChanges

Tags: breeze

On client I am creating object "A" and saving it. On BeforeSaveEntity (on server) additionally is created/modified object "B" and this object is returned together with object "A" to the client (thanks to bug fix in version 1.3.5 - which I am using). 
However when object "B" returns to client the initializer of this entity is not called (at least it looks like that) however the entity constructor is called.

Am I doing something wrong or this could be some other issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kris,

We were not able to reproduce the problem.
In our testing the initializer for entity "B" (created on server) is called.

Note that, according to your post, you are creating/modifying entity "B" in BeforeSaveEntity that is called for entity "A". 
You should NOT do that. BeforeSaveEntity is meant to handle the entity in case only - i.e. entity "A" in this situation.
If you are creating/modifying other entities, you should do so in BeforeSaveEntities and ensure you add/remove them in the saveMap. More on that at http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/custom-efcontextprovider.

Comment: The real thing is that adding new entity I am doing on BeforeSaveEntities and it works. However modifying I am doing on BeforeSaveEntity which is not working. Any way thanks for tip.

Comment: I'm confused now. Please clarify your two statements: (1) Did you just say that when you create the new entity on BeforeSaveEntities the initializer is called? (2) Did you state that when you modify the entity on BeforeSaveEntity the initializer is NOT called?

Comment: Adding up to (2): When you modify an entity, the initializer is NOT called - only when you create a new entity.